# How to have a Swift package and iOS target in the same project?

Tags: xcode

I was watching a WWDC video and they have a Swift Package and Swift app in the same project. How do you create that in Xcode? If I create a new Swift Package, I'm not able to add another target in the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That was tricky, at first I thought It was created by adding a local swift package. Then I discovered the created structure does not look like your screen capture.

So after research I found it was actually a `xcworkspace` that joined the swift Package and app together.

How to create it?
First you should create a normal swift package in Xcode with `File` -> `New` -> `Packages`

Then you are going to drag the `xcodeproj` file of the MyApp to the top of Xcode's left panel. You will be asked if you want to create a xcworkspace? just check yes.

I have uploaded to code to github, take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/kasimok/73709383)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! When I try this it works, but when I try to make a new app target in the workspace Xcode 14 crashes.